# Android layer-list with nine-patch surrounding a bitmap

Tags: android, nine-patch, layer-list

I have a simple layer list with a bitmap and a shadow around that bitmap as a nine-patch drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/canvas_image_layer_id">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bitmap" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/background_shadow">
        <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/shadow"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Like this, the nine patch drawable is inside the bitmap and not around it, even though the nine patch is set up correctly with the stretchable and content markup and works fine if set as the background attribute of an ImageView.

Unfortunately I can't simply use the nine patch as background of the bitmap because the bitmap is transformed by matrix (two finger pinch & zoom) and the background attribute doesn't adhere to the image matrix.

There is no margin or padding attribute for the nine-patch item. What is the correct way to make the nine-patch act as a frame around the bitmap?

Comment: it is set in android:src. otherwise it would not be transformable with a matrix.

Comment: The nine patch is transformed by the matrix but the frame part of the nine patch is not outside the bitmap but the inside.

Comment: I want the content part of the nine patch to line up with the outside of the bitmap.

Comment: Managed to get this working with a negative inset for the shadow :) thanks!